# Browser making two request when i access a image

Tags: apache, security, ssl, browser, https

My browser is making two request when i access the image on url, this happen only over https

For example: 
I have a image on: https://example.com/icon.ico 
when i access this url, the browser making two requests
GET /icon.ico 
GET /icon.ico 
[image]

And with http only:
[image]

Can you help-me?

Comment: What is the status against the first request , in the screen shot it appears to be 404 , can you confirm ?

Comment: The first request in this case  is 304 because the cache, but normally is 200 too.